# How to handle multiple select statment with union all

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to get the results by using multiple SQL statements with union all, this is like:

```
select column1,column2 from table1 where column4 ='value1' union all
select column1,column2 from table1 where column4 ='value2' union all
select column1,column2 from table1 where column4 ='value3' union all
select column1,column2 from table1 where column4 ='value4' union all
select column1,column2 from table1 where column4 ='value5'
```

for above, i will get only two results:

```
column1  column2
XXXXX    XXXXX
XXXXX   XXXXX
```

Because no results for another 2 select queries. But I need to record null values or no values in resultant table like:

```
column1  column2
XXXXX    XXXXX
Null     Null
XXXXX    XXXXX
Null     Null
```

How can get these kind of results??

whether I can handle nulls by using if statement in multiple sql statements.

Comment: How many records would each query in the union generate?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but the most literal way to get what you want could be

```
select coloumn1,coloumn2 from table1 where coloumn4 ='value1' union all
SELECT Null, Null WHERE NOT EXISTS(select coloumn1,coloumn2 from table1 where coloumn4 ='value1') union all
select coloumn1,coloumn2 from table1 where coloumn4 ='value2' union all
SELECT Null, Null WHERE NOT EXISTS(select coloumn1,coloumn2 from table1 where coloumn4 ='value2') union all
select coloumn1,coloumn2 from table1 where coloumn4 ='value3' union all
SELECT Null, Null WHERE NOT EXISTS(select coloumn1,coloumn2 from table1 where coloumn4 ='value3') union all
select coloumn1,coloumn2 from table1 where coloumn4 ='value4' union all
SELECT Null, Null WHERE NOT EXISTS(select coloumn1,coloumn2 from table1 where coloumn4 ='value4') union all
select coloumn1,coloumn2 from table1 where coloumn4 ='value5'
SELECT Null, Null WHERE NOT EXISTS(select coloumn1,coloumn2 from table1 where coloumn4 ='value5')
```

Comment: This will work but is absolute brute-force method. Should look at one of the other set-based solutions, which are also far shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `UNION ALL` you would probably be far better off using a CTE to create a list of values, and then `LEFT JOIN`. This stops you needing to scan the table 5 times:

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT Column4
    FROM (VALUES('value1'),('value2'),('value3'),('value4'),('value5')) V(Column4))
SELECT YT.Column1, YT.Column2, V.Column4
FROM VTE V
     LEFT JOIN YourTable YT ON V.Column4 = YT.Column4;
```

Comment: Almost the same, but neater than mine due to the Table Value Constructor. Both much better than the accepted answer though.

Comment: @TomC agrees. That other answer will result in 5 scans of the table, rather than just the 1.

Comment: 10 scans actually. More annoying @Larnu is that my single downvote earned me 6 revenge downvotes on other answers dating back to 1st August. Very petty.

Comment: @TomC I see both of our answer were downvoted. Perhaps the person who did would like to explain why they downvote our answers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table variable for the values which you want to search. And then use a `LEFT JOIN` with the other table.

**Query**

```
declare @t as table(
    [column4] varchar(100)
);

insert into @t
select 'value1' union all
select 'value2' union all
select 'value3' union all
select 'value4' union all
select 'value5';

select [t2].[column1], [t2].[column2]
from @t as [t1]
left join [table1] as [t2]
on [t1].[column4] = [t2].[column4];
```

Comment: @downvoter : You are supposed to comment the issue found with my code to do the downvote.

Comment: Looks like someone downvoted every answer here, apart from Cato's. Very odd/telling behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTE:

```
;with vals as (
    select 'value1' as val
    union select 'value2'
    union select 'value3'
    union select 'value4'
    union select 'value5'
)
select coloumn1,coloumn2 
from vals
left join table1 on table1.coloumn4 =val
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use a description column to answer this type of code

```
select 'Value1' AS Value ,
        coloumn1,
        coloumn2 

from table1 

where coloumn4 ='value1' 

union all


select 'Value2' AS Value ,
        coloumn1,
        coloumn2 

from table1 

where coloumn4 ='value2' 

union all

select 'Value3' AS Value ,
        coloumn1,
        coloumn2 

from table1 

where coloumn4 ='value3' 

union all

select 'Value4' AS Value ,
        coloumn1,
        coloumn2 

from table1 

where coloumn4 ='value4' 

union all

select 'Value5' AS Value ,
        coloumn1,
        coloumn2 

from table1 

where coloumn4 ='value5'
```